# How can i check if an audio is empty?

Tags: javascript, http, httpresponse, html5-audio, audio-streaming

```
const radio = new Audio('http://myradiostation.com/stream');
```

Is there a way to know if `radio` is empty (has no sound/audio)?

Sometimes the radio host forgets to turn on the stream, and I would like to give the end user some feedback when this occurs. Something like an `alert` that says *"The radio host forgot to turn on the stream!!!"*

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
if(radio.isEmpty){
    alert('The radio host forgot to turn on the stream!!!')
}else{
    radio.play()
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following did the trick:

```
 const radio = new Audio('http://myradiostation.com/stream');

  radio
    .play()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('success');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert('The radio host forgot to turn on the stream!!!');
    });
```